# Can I reproduce this full screen flash animation with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, animation

Please excuse me if this is not possible, but I am looking for some direction on reproducing this animation without using flash.

The animation can be found on http://flatuicolors.com/ 
It occurs when you click a color, triggering a full screen animation with text.

I am not looking for specific code, just some ideas on if/how this is possible to simulate with JS/jQuery, the core functionality being triggering a similar animation on click with text. It only needs to be functional on desktop, as it would be used in a webapp that would not require it for mobile.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Are you sure flash is used ?

Comment: Everything is possible.

Comment: @NathanP., just right click on the color, it'll give you the answer!

Comment: @Karl Actually I cannot right-click on any color, and I can't see any swf, or flash stuff into the source code. I am using chromium under Arch Linux

Comment: Yes you can do this with JQuery easily...have a fix element in the background...change z-position after click...do some animating of the text-banners dimensions to get the zoom-out effect...

Comment: @NathanP. well then, no it is not in flash.

Comment: @Wex  - serious question since i am new to SO and front end in general - what would be a more fitting/helpful way to ask this question, seeing as I am looking for a bit of direction and not specific comments/debugging help on existing code?

Comment: Asking it in chat rather than as a question might be more acceptable. (not sure, i rarely use chat). Your question is leading toward a yes or no answer. It's typically a bad idea to ask "Is it possible" simply because the answer is almost always "Yes" in one way or another unless the question is VERY specific.

Comment: @NathanP. I actually thought it was flash at first just because the right-click didn't work :) I'm also using chromium under Arch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's just an overlay element that's fading out.

The text-zooming-out illusion could be created by animating the font-size.

Here's a simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wbFUP/2/ using

```
.animate()
```

Comment: perfect, thank you for the fiddle and simple solution.